# User can still view pervious page after logout in grails

Tags: grails

In my grails project, i am using spring security core plugin. I have provided logout link as

```
<g:link controller="logout">Logout</g:link> in my gsp pages.
```

Code in LogoutController as :

```
class LogoutController {

/**
 * Index action. Redirects to the Spring security logout uri.
 */
def index = {
    // TODO put any pre-logout code here
        session.invalidate()
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
 }
}
```

When user clicks it, it redirects user to login page. But if user clicks browser's back button, user is able to see previous working page. I don't want to redirect him to previous page & he should stay on login page. What can i do for it?

Additional info : I have created one tag library which check login user's username. If its anonymous, it redirects to login page or send it to home page. But working of it,user must click on something. Because currently after logout,user can see previous page by clicking on back button. I don't want to redirect him on previous page. He should stay on login page.

Comment: session.invalidate() is not necessary. The back button reload the page or is cached in the browser? Is the page correctly mapped for authentication? You can also check remember me cookie.

Comment: Its showing cached page in browser.Where is that remember me cookie setting ?

Comment: If it's cached then is all right. The remember me is normally a checkbox in the login form. Or can be configured using spring security core params see http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/22%20Miscellaneous%20Properties.html

Comment: It's a cached sir.Because when i clicked back button,its showing me previous page, but if i click on any element like menu or button it redirects me to the login form.So no issue there.But user can see previous page is my problem. So its a kind of security issue.

Comment: If is an old visited not updated browser cached page there is no security issue and there is no way to prevent it. Anyone could save any protected web page for later display. I login, I open a protected report, I save it on desktop and I do logout. Then I coult still open it one hour, one mounth o years later. I can even share it by email or other method and this no way to prevent it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much Fabiano Taioli sir for clearing my doubt. I thought it's a security issue.Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Simple ,just put this code in all your Pages:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");  

response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");     

response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 

response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");

%>
```

Comment: We do use layout in grails and we normally use different layout for login-ed pages. So we need to put the above code only on layout page.

Comment: You are very correct Ramsharan,putting the above ina Template or a filter is mre efficient

Comment: @Ramsharam ,Agreed the above can be put in the layout.gsp in grails but if using spring or any other framework ,you can include it in an include.jsp and then include the file in all your pages.If using plain html you can use the meta tags for the above